# Is it possible to identify exact GPU type using miner's log file?

Tags: gpu, gpu-mining

In the miners (`sgminer`) log file I have the following lines:

```
[21:14:19] ADL index 0, id -546853344 - BIOS partno.: 113-C3865001-T04, version: 015.041.000.000.000000, date: 11/25/13 02:47
[21:14:19] GPU 0 assigned: iAdapterIndex:0 iPresent:1 strUDID:256:26520:4098:12289:5963 iBusNumber:1 iDeviceNumber:0 iDrvIndex:0 iFunctionNumber:0 iVendorID:4098 name:AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
```

Can I use the information above to identify the exact GPU type? It's clear about the `AMD Radeon R9 200 Series` family, but I need the exact type also.

Is there any database I can use?